# Can I tell an adapter to use a differently-named serializer?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, adapter, serialization

I have an adapter named `xyz`. I want to point it to a serializer called `abc`, NOT `xyz`. Is it possible to do this? I have tried to set the [defaultSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#property_defaultSerializer) property, but it didn't work.

In other words, normal data flow is:

Adapter: `xyz` > Serializer: `xyz` > Model: `xyz`.

Data flow I would like:

Adapter: `xyz` > Serializer: `abc` > Model: `abc`, where a model `xyz` would not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of a direct way, but you can make a workaround. Create a serializer for `xyz` and extend the serializer from `abc`.

```
ember g serializer xyz
```

Then in the `xyz` serializer.

```
import ABCSerializer from './abc';

export default ABCSerializer.extend({})
```

Comment: i figured this was the only way. i ended up doing this, but i'll wait a bit just in case by some miracle someone has an actual way

Comment: note: i didn't use the `.extend` part. you should really only need to do this if you want to add functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You may create an application serializer, which will be used if there is no model-specific one

Comment: But I can't tell my adapter to use a specific serializer?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please, describe what problem are you trying to solve.